# Can I use 'iw' to create multiple virtual interfaces to connect to multiple networks?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I'm trying to connect one computer to two others in an ad-hoc infrastructure.

```
[computer 1] ---- [computer 2] ---- [computer 3]
```

`computer 2` is running Linux and has a single NIC `wlan0`. I want to it to connect to both `computer 1` and `computer 3` so each computer can talk to the other. No switch is available so it needs to be an ad-hoc setup.

What I was thinking was:

```
[computer 1]
    wlan0: 192.168.1.1

[computer 2]
    wlan0: 192.168.1.2
    wlan1: 192.168.1.3

[computer 3]
    wlan0: 192.168.1.4
```

For this exmaple, `computer 2` can be the 'access point' for the others.

```
[computer 2]
iwconfig wlan0 essid adhoc1 mode ad-hoc
iwconfig wlan1 essid adhoc2 mode ad-hoc
```

The other computers could then connect to `computer 2` and I'd have a network.

Is this possible? If so, are there any problems that will arise from doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Runnning into a similar problem I am about to try spoofing the MAC of the 2nd and 3rd virtual devices so that ifconfig can up them.  just an idea. however I doubt it will work since

```
iw phy0 info
```

produces a line

> HT TX Max spatial streams: 1

my hope is that

> max # scan SSID: 4

might be multiple connections.

Edit:
spoofing the MAC by doing a

```
ip link set wlan1 addres xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx up
```

does not work and produces a changed MAC for the virtual device but complains

> RTNETLINK answers: No buffer space available

Imo my device is limited, but maybe using a IBSS, mesh, or some other method could work.  kernel 3.x opens up a lot more functions with iw to try out.  Happy hacking

Answer (score 0):

Most WLAN adapters can only be connected to one remote MAC address at a time (and you probably don't have one of the ones that can be connected to multiple addresses; they're quite rare). You'll need a second adapter to make this work.

Comment: What then is the purpose of creating virtual interfaces with `iw`?

Comment: It's for one of those WLAN adapters that *does* support multiple addresses.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. On the off chance I have one of these rare WLAN adapters, how do I test it? Do I have to setup my described network and see if it works or is there a quicker way?

Comment: I'm not really sure; I've never worked with such a device in-depth (I *have* one, I just haven't done much with it).